# Uncaught TypeError while importing from firebase/database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

error that i'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "firebase/database". Relative references must start with either "/",
> "./", or "../".

i am trying to setup firebase configuration for the latest version of firebase 9.1

```
<script type="module">

    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-app.js";
  
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "....",
        appId: "..."
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    //below import statement is causing the error
    import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

    const db = getDatabase();
    
    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" >

            function InsertData() {
                set(ref(db, 'TheStudent/'+rollV), {
                    NameOfStudent: "abc",
                    RollNo: 13,
                    Section: "B",
                    Gender: "Male"
                });
            }

            document.getElementById('insertBtn').onclick = InsertData;
</script>
```

PS. i have hidden the config on purpose, so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Firebase SDK over CDN so try importing database in same way:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-database.js";
// CDN URL instead of "firebase/database"
```

Comment: now its saying set is not defined, see the code i updated.

Comment: @HassaanRaza can you try moving your code in same `<script>`  tag ?

Comment: the problem was import statement has only the scope of current script tag so it was not working in another script, i put all my code in the same scirpt it works like a charm, thank you so much.